# Filter column based on two conditions spark and Java

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add a filter on my dataframe, for some reason the || condition is not working in Java, it works perfectly in Scala. The code doesn't even compile. How do we use || operator in filter condition in java

The message says

```
The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column

df.filter((df.col("eventNumbers").contains("2") )|| (df.col("eventNumbers").contains("45")))
```

Comment: did you `import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;`?

Comment: Yes, import is already in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

And that scala code in java would be:

```
df.filter((df.col("eventNumbers").contains("2") ).or(df.col("eventNumbers").contains("45")))
```

Comment: Me trying to write this vals_df.drop(col("lastStagedTs")).filter(col("BENCHMARK_TYPE_CODE") === "PERCENTILE_50")   in Java ... but getting error "The method filter(Column) in the type Dataset<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean) "   how to fix this ?

Comment: I tried this way too     vals_df.filter(vals_df.col(" BENCHMARK_TYPE_CODE").equals("PERCENTILE_50"))  this gives error "The method filter(Column) in the type Dataset<Row> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)"

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, you can use String `conditionExpr` to filter.

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().read()
    .option("multiLine", true)
    .json(dnsRecordFile)
    .filter("type=='A'")  // <--- filter by ConditionExpr Str
    .select("name", "value");
```